# React components are not rendering/not showing up on browser

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router-v4, babel-loader, webpack-4

I have a react project with all the latest npm packages. Please check github link for package.json file

I can see the bundle.js file created and my components on chrome developers tools, however I cannot see those components render on browser.

[git repo](https://github.com/code2design/react-redux-app)

Please refer to image below
[image]

React devtool tab

[image]

Comment: The image shows that there are errors in the console. What are the errors?

Comment: let me upload another image. I don't know why it shows. But there are no errors. Thanks

Comment: What can you see inside React tab (chrome devtools) ?

Comment: I have added snapshoot of react devtool tab. It looks like something is wrong with react-router but I can't figure out

Comment: Inside your `routes.js` you are not using `<Route>` Correctly : Make sure you are wrapping entire Route block with switch `<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" component={App} />   </Switch>`

Comment: you can actually just remove switch, as you only have one route...

Comment: There is more than one route , I have just mentioned one as a guide

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the way I was using react-router-dom. The updated version does the support the way we used to pass nested routes to a parent routes where it used to render.

If anyone have same issues then refer to this awesome example guide. 
[react router 4 awesome example](https://css-tricks.com/react-router-4/)